# Detect user source from chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I detect if the user is coming from chrome app, the check.php page will be displayed differently to someone coming directly and someone coming from the chrome app.

```
{
  "name": "New App",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
  "launch": {
      "web_url": "example.com/check.php"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "l.png"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
"launch": {
    "web_url": "example.com/check.php?source=app"
}
```

On the PHP side, check the `$_GET['source']` variable. If it's `app`, it's coming from the chrome app.

FWIW, it's how the Chrome Web Store does it for their app. They check the `utm_source` variable for the `chrome-ntp-icon` value.

Comment: No, and it wouldn't matter much since it's as hidden/spoofable as a get.